# How do i share the .aab with testing team

Tags: java, android, firebase, apk, firebase-app-distribution

Currently we are exporting APK to the play store and we are using Firebase app distribution for our testing track but now we want to start using App bundles instead of APK but the issue here that Firebase app distribution does not support. After a long search i found about "internal app sharing method". But i my case thats doesnt work, my testers are facing lots of issue with that url. Is there any other way to share .aab to testers / others customers?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/test

Comment: Don't use internal testing otherwise you will face https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67106945/android-play-console-internal-test-track-is-not-usable-when-version-code-in-oth issue.